# Replacing a standalone & with &amp; in Java

Tags: java

In Java I want to replace standalone ampersands -&- with -&amp;- but not if it is followed by any number, letter or special character.  I have tried

```
messageText = messageText.replaceAll("&(?![a-z0-9#]{1,6};)","&amp;");
```

but it fails when the # is in the string and ' is converted to &amp;#39;

Comment: can you also show the original text(messageText) and the desired output?

Comment: What was your input?

Comment: your code does not behave the way you described: it replaces all & with &amp; regardless of the next character.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?  Most frameworks that construct HTML or XML documents will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Put your special characters in the `special` string.

```
String special = "a-z0-9#!.'-@"; // change as required
String pat = "&(?![" + special +"])";
String s = "this & is &25 &! #24 'f' &' a & b";
s = s.replaceAll(pat, "&amp;");
System.out.println(s);
```

Prints

```
this &amp; is &25 &! #24 'f' &' a &amp; b
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  Tests running fine.

Comment: Great.  Keep in mind that that the special characters are ultimately part of a character class ( between [])  so  you need to position  your characters accordingly (e.g don't put ^ at the beginning of the list).